# How to check in Python if a key:value exists in an array (key:value) exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of key:value pairs which I am generating using a loop over the contents (entity extraction) of documents.

```
entity_array.append({
    "key": entity.label_,
    "value": entity.text
})
```

I would like to add in a check that if the key of value already exists don't append but unsure how using key AND value. The reason being I am getting a lot of duplicate rows.

I'm able to check if the key OR value exists but this doesn't give the desired result as an entity could belong to multiple keys.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure I am getting this right, are you trying to deduplicate identical values of `entity.text` regardless of `entity.label_`, or are you trying to deduplicate identical _combinations_ of `entity.text` and `entity.label_`?

Comment: Trying to deduplicate identical combinations of entity.text and entity.label_

Comment: If you have unique key-value pairs, is there a reason why you are not using a `set` of `namedtuple` (or `tuple` or a custom class)? Checking membership in a `list` is super ineffective. Or if you want efficient lookup by key, a `dict` of `set`?

Comment: I am still confused on what you are looking for.  Why couldn't you make a dict-of-dict with the outer dict having key constructed by the interested fields?  Can you make a clearer example, with input and expected output to demonstrate your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the data structure you are using is causing you some issues.  If you want to keep track of duplicate combinations of `entity.label_` and `entity.text` values, consider treating the combination as a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) and using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to quickly check for duplicates:

```
import collections

Entity = collections.namedtuple("Entity", ["key", "value"])  # a tuple called "Entity" with named elements
entity_set = set()  # empty set where we will store deduplicated combinations of label and text

for entity in your_iterable_here:
    entity_set.add(Entity(key=entity.label_, value=entity.text))  # add to the set if it's not there already, otherwise do nothing
```

You can even do this as a one-liner if you want:

```
entity_set = set(Entity(key=entity.label_, value=entity.text) for entity in your_iterable_here)
```

When you are done, you will have a collection of unique key/value pairs in `entity_set`.  If you absolutely need the entities in the data structure mentioned in the OP (a list of dicts), one option is to take advantage of the [namedtuple._asdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict) function (which, despite the underscore in the name, is a fully documented function and a part of the "public" namedtuple interface):

```
entity_array = [entity._asdict() for entity in entity_set]
```

There are two caveats to this solution:

1. Whatever `entity._label` and `entity.text` are, they must be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) to be put into a `set`.  There are ways around this if the things you are storing are not simple values like strings, but it can get complicated.
2. The order of the entities generated by `your_iterable_here` will not be preserved.  There easy ways around this, like using an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) with `Entity` keys and `bool` values instead of a set.

Answer (score 0):

you can implements your own function for that, example you can call `get` method with given key and compare the returned value with your spected value:

```py
def exists(dict_:dict, key:str, value:object) -> bool:
    return dict_.get(key) == value
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check two conditions - (a) if the key is not present in the target dictionary, and (b) if the key is present but the value is different. In both cases, you will have to add the new value to the dictionary.

For e.g., suppose dict{} is your main dictionary, and values_to_add below is a new dictionary that has some values that need to be added to dict{}. The below code does what you're looking to do:

```
from itertools import combinations
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random as rd

dict = {
    "Key_1": "Value_1",
    "Key_2": "Value_2",
    "Key_3": "Value_3"
}

values_to_add = {
    "Key_1": "Value_X",
    "Key_4": "Value_4"
}

for key,value in values_to_add.items():
    if key in dict and dict[key] != value:
        dict[key]=value
    if not key in dict:
        dict[key] = value

dict
```